# I want to render the page on Next.js conditionally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-effect

I have the following code on my -app.js:

```
  import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
  import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    
    ...


export default function MyApp(props) {
  const { Component, pageProps } = props;
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);

  //this prop will be passed to all the pages
  const passedProps = {
    ...pageProps,
    cartItems: cartItems,
    setCartItems: setCartItems,
  };

  ...

    //on App load do the following:
      useEffect(() => {
       
    ...

    //get cart items from  localstorage if exist,else set to empty array;
    const savedCartItems = localStorage.getItem("cartItems"),
      cartItems = JSON.parse(savedCartItems) || [];
    setCartItems(cartItems);
  }, []);

  return (
  
        ...
        <Component {...passedProps} />
      ...
    </>
  );
}

MyApp.propTypes = {
  Component: PropTypes.elementType.isRequired,
  pageProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Following is the code on checkout.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

...
export default function Checkout(props) {
     router = useRouter(),
    { cartItems } = props;

 ...
  // on checkout page load if cart is empty redirect to carts page
  useEffect(() => {
    !cartItems.length && router.push("/cart");
  }, [cartItems, router]);

 ...
  return (
   ...
}

Checkout.propTypes = {
  cartItems: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      title: PropTypes.string,
      variations: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.object),
      qty: PropTypes.number,
      price: PropTypes.number,
    })
  ),
};
```

I need to redirect from checkout page to cart page only if the cart is empty, but I am being redirected every time even when the cart has items. I think it's because of the fact that on the initial page load, items have still not been loaded to the parent-app component from local storage and are still undefined. any solutions to this??

Comment: So do you want the redirect to happen only on pageload? if someone adds an item to card on the page later, it should not redirect?

Comment: checkout is a separate page. checkout should redirect immediately if there are no items in cart. suppose someone types the following address in url: localhost/checkout. now if cart is empty he should be redirected to carts page instead. did you get my point??

Comment: is your router react router dom?

Comment: no its "next/router".

Comment: its not a router issue though, its happening because of use effect, due to SSR in next.js i have to redirect in useEffect. problem is at the start items have not been loaded from local storage and cart is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is because you initialized `cartItems` with an empty array, which has a length of 0, so this always execute:

```js
!cartItems.length && router.push("/cart");
```

Instead, initialize it without a value:

```js
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState();
```

and change the useEffect to:

```js
  // on page Load,if cart is empty redirect to carts page
  useEffect(() => {
    if (Array.isArray(cartItems) && cartItems.length === 0) {
      router.push("/cart");
    }
  }, [cartItems, router]);
```

This way, the redirect will only execute when:

1. The cartItems has been set in the parent
2. It is not empty.

Comment: !cartItems.length will return false on non-empty array and shouldn't execute. it will execute only if value of length is 0.since zero is falsy and greater than zero is truthy.i tried this before. problem is not in initialization, its in loading of the items from local storage to parent. i tried your answer already.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy    null and undefined are also falsy. so zero is equal to null or undefined when being used for conditional statements

Comment: I understand what falsy values are. By always execute, I mean that on initial react render, the state is initialized with an empty array, so the check returns true. Then the useEffect in the parent that gets the item from local storage happens, and it updates the state, but by this time the redirect has already happened. If you say you've already tried this and it's not working, can you please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then?

Comment: ok i will give it one more try and give you feedback. thanks for your response.

Comment: No problem, and falsy is exactly why I'm using `Array.isArray` to explicitly check that the localStorage operation has already happened, instead of `!carsItems.length`, since that will not work even if you initialize to null.

Comment: i did what you suggested but still same behaviour, i have edited my code now as per your suggestion, and edited my question

Comment: It works just fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-robinson-gp8tf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i think behavour of CRA is differenct from next.js its not working in my case, i consoled log carts in use effect with dependecy of cart items and it just logged undefined.

Comment: Array.isArray(cartItems) &&
      cartItems.length === 0   you wrote in your answer > 0 instead of === and i copied the same without checking, my bad. great and correct answer. thanks

Comment: Ah I apologize, that’s my mistake, edited to fix!

Comment: encountered a similar problem, where I want to redirect user under a condition, use `useEffect` to make this a client side code for `router.push()`, a good way to solve in react way